# Audio loop. (discord.py)

Tags: python, button, discord, discord.py, bots

I want the new sound to start only after the old one ends, but the only way to do that is to use the "after" argument in VoiceClient.play, which is only acceptable when I'm using context, not interaction. So I use a while loop and async.sleep there, which is also not the best option because the audio may delay or be paused, which means the timer should also be paused. How should I do it?

Also, the button that is supposed to loop the sound turns gray when a new sound starts.
I've already tried to add some condition to the "style" argument like "if loop then color.green else color.grey", but it didn't work.

In addition, I'm wondering if there is a way to remove the followup.send messages after a while because the "ephemeral" tag doesn't work.

```py
queue = []
loop = False

@tree.command(name = "cplay", description = "Turns on audio in the voice channel", guild = discord.Object(id = guildid))
async def cplay(interaction: discord.Interaction, query: str):
    global response, voice, queue
    await interaction.response.defer()
    if not interaction.user.voice or not interaction.user.voice.channel.id == audioid:
        erroremb = discord.Embed(title = "Error.", description = "You are not connected to a music channel.", color = 0xBC2C2C)
        await interaction.followup.send(embed = erroremb)
        errorres = await interaction.original_response()
        return await errorres.edit(delete_after = 10)
    elif re.match("^https?:\\/\\/(?:www\\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\\+~#=]{1,256}\\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\\b(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\\+.~#?&//=]*)$", query):
        if not re.match("^(http(s)?://)?((w){3}.)?youtu(be|.be)?(.com)?/.+", query):
            erroremb = discord.Embed(title = "Error.", description = "Currently, the bot only supports audio from YouTube.", color = 0xBC2C2C)
            await interaction.followup.send(embed = erroremb)
            errorres = await interaction.original_response()
            return await errorres.edit(delete_after = 10)
        else: url = query
    else: url = (await VideosSearch(query, limit = 1).next())["result"][0]["link"]
    if not interaction.guild.voice_client: await client.get_channel(audioid).connect()
    voice = interaction.guild.voice_client
    queue.append(url)
    if voice.is_playing():
        addedemb = discord.Embed(title = "Added to the queue.", description = url, color = 0x228B22)
        await interaction.followup.send(embed = addedemb)
        addedres = await interaction.original_response()
        return await addedres.edit(delete_after = 10)
    success = discord.Embed(title = "Please wait.", description = "Audio is loading...", color = 0xFFD700)
    await interaction.followup.send(embed = success)
    response = await interaction.original_response()
    await start_audio(queue)

async def start_audio(queue):
    while queue:
        with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(queue[0], download = False)
        voice.play(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(info["url"])))
        player = discord.Embed(title = info["title"], url = queue[0], color = 0x228B22)
        player.set_author(name = info["uploader"], url = info["uploader_url"])
        player.set_thumbnail(url = info["thumbnail"])
        player.add_field(name = "Duration", value = duration_format(info['duration']))
        await response.edit(embed = player, view = AudioPlayer(timeout = None))
        await asyncio.sleep(info["duration"])
        if not loop: queue.pop(0)
    error = discord.Embed(title = "Playback stopped.", description = "The list of audio recordings in the queue has run out.", color = 0xBC2C2C)
    await response.edit(embed = error, view = None, delete_after = 30)

class AudioPlayer(discord.ui.View):
    @discord.ui.button(emoji = "")
    async def loop(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.defer()
        global loop
        if loop:
            loop = False
            button.style = discord.ButtonStyle.grey
            await response.edit(view = self)
        else:
            loop = True
            button.style = discord.ButtonStyle.green
            await response.edit(view = self)

# I do realize that my code is crap, so I would also be glad to get some recommendations on how to fix it.
```